# Black Ops 2 is freezing

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I have been having very bad issues with my Black Ops 2.

First, it disconnected me from online every time I tried, so I stopped playing it for about 4 months.

That problem stopped, and now it keeps on freezing on the multiplayer match load screen. It works just fine on zombies and campaign. I have done everything I could find to fix it, but it doesn't work. I even got another XBox, and that didn't work.

The disk is in perfect condition no scratches whatsoever, and it works just fine on my friends PS3.

Comment: What, what?  Are you playing on PS3, or XBox?  The disks are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem when running Black Ops 2 on a old piano-style 20GB PS3.  Thinking that the PS3 was just too old, I got a Slim from Ebay.  But it kept crashing in multiplayer - in the same way as the old PS3.  I tried cooling it with a massive fan, hoovering out all the fluff, etc. with no effect.

As a last-ditch attempt, I took the disk (which looked absolutely flawless) back to the shop, got a replacement, and this works PERFECTLY.  Honestly, I was quite shocked.

My guess is that there are a number of disks out there which are faulty (bad pressings?).  The manufacturers will expect some faulty disks, but maybe this game has a few too many - given that so many people have similar problems.

What probably makes the problem worse is that the faulty disks make their way onto the secondhand market, as people are so fed-up with them.  That just passes the problem on to someone else...